# IValueConverter refresh

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy implementando un menú con seguridad, de forma que según la seguridad del usuario verá o no los elementos del menú.

Para ello tengo una entidad llamada UserSecurity de la forma:

```
public class UserSecurity :BaseEntity
{
    public int? UserSecurityId { get; set; }

    public int? UserId
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(() => UserId);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(() => UserId, value);
        }
    }

    public string MenuName
    {
        get
        {

            return GetValue(() => MenuName);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(() => MenuName, value);
        }
    }

    public bool Visibility
    {
        get
        {

            return GetValue(() => Visibility);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(() => Visibility, value);
        }
    }

}
```

donde BaseEntity contiene la implementación de INotifyPropertyChanged a través de GetValue() y SetValue(). Esta seguridad se asocia al usuario de la forma:

```
 public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    public bool Active
    {
        get
        {

            return GetValue(() => Active);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(() => Active, value);
        }
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {

            return GetValue(() => UserName);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(() => UserName, value);
        }
    }


    public virtual ICollection<UserSecurity> UserSecurities
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(() => UserSecurities);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(() => UserSecurities, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Los usuarios y su seghuridad se acrgan al iniciar sesión en la aplicación, y funcionan correctamente a través de un CustomConverter:

```
public class PermissionToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        string propertyName = parameter as string;

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            return value;

        foreach(var security in user.UserSecurities)
        {
            if (security.MenuName == propertyName)
                return (security.Visibility == true ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible : System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        return value;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

donde user es una variable global que contiene los datos del usuario y su seguridad. La visibilidad en el menú se implementa de la siguiente forma:

```
Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ptvConverter}, ConverterParameter=Company}"
```

aunque esta implementación funciona correctamente, ahora quiero que, si modifico la seguridad, los menús correspondientes se muestren u oculten. Para ello recardo el objeto user, lo cual no se traduce en que se actualicen los cambios a nivel visual.

¿Como puedo hacer que la capa UI vea esos cambios y "recalcule" el valor visibility con el CustomConverter?

Gracias.

Comment: En principio, si en tu `BaseEntity` implementas `INotifyPropertyChanged`, el UI debería actualizarse automáticamente. Sin ver la implementación de `BaseEntity` no puedo decirte mas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en la forma de bindear la visibilitty. Te explico, estas haciendo un binding ciego, y el converter no vuelve a saltar, cuando cambia el valor. Ha esto error te ha llevado utilizar la clase estática. Esta clase estática la tienes que recibir dentro dle parámetro value del converter, para que él lo detecte.

```
Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ptvConverter}, ConverterParameter=Company}"
```

Ha este binding le falta la propiedad Path, algo así:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path="Model.Campo_INotifyPropertyChanged", Converter={StaticResource ptvConverter}, ConverterParameter=Company}"
```

Ósea, que o bien tienes que crearte una propiedad en tu ViewModel, supongo que estarás utilizando MVVM, y asignarle tu User (Stático), o bien bindearle directamente el campo estático con {x:static ...} en el binding.

Answer (score 0):

Para que se actualice la UI al cambiar los valores de un objeto y SIN necesidad de recargar el objeto debes implementar correctamente INotifyPropertyChanged, y esto se hará en el SET de cada propiedad, luego de asignar el value le agregas otra linea para decirle a la UI que se actualice.. tu implementación es un tanto extraña para mi, pero el concepto es este..

Así lo tienes

```
set
{
  SetValue(() => UserSecurities, value);
}
```

Así debería ser:

```
set
{
  SetValue(() => UserSecurities, value);
   if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyProperty"));
}
```

Entonces cada vez que haya un cambio la UI se actualizará, para esto debes -como ya dije- implementar INotifypropertyChanged en todas las clases involucradas para que el cambio se transmita hasta llegar a la interfaz.